# Creating a slanted button on top and bottom

Tags: html, css, skew

I am trying to create a button with two slanted lines. One from the bottom left to the right center which I managed. The next one needs to be from the top left to the right.

The height of the left side is `50px` and the height of the right side should be `30px`

```css
.slantedButton {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #3c50a2;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slantedButton:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: inherit;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skewY(-4deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="slantedButton">Hello World!</div>
```

I tried to do this with a `:before` but this didn't work out.

Suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works find using `::before`. Just change the `transform-origin`:

```css
.slantedButton {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #3c50a2;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slantedButton:before, .slantedButton:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: inherit;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.slantedButton:before {
    transform-origin: top right;
    transform: skewY(4deg);
}

.slantedButton:after {
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skewY(-4deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="slantedButton">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. But this is not the result I was looking for. The result should be is that there should be a slanting line from the top left to the right. Just like I have from the bottom left to the right.